# Circular progress bar with triangle line cap - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressbar

I want to create a circular progress bar that has triangle line cap (Triangle tip) and also I need to show a text in the tip of the progression. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Please show your effort first then tell us about the problems you are facing.

Comment: I've designed it already but i dunno how to make to behave it with that corresponding criteria

Comment: I didn't ask a code for that operation. I just asked a help and it may be anything like a simple logic. "You want us to code for you?"  What do you mean ? I was expecting a pretty decent replies !! Anyways I'll take care of it. Thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer by adding rotated square with the circle by an position animation :) :) If possible, I can upload the code :) :)